# Dialog doesn't stay child of parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom, jquery-ui-dialog

If I do this:

```
$("#my_button").click(function(){
    $("<div />")
    .appendTo("#main_section")
});
```

The resulting `div` is a child of `#main_section`. However when I do this:

```
$("#my_button").click(function(){
    $("<div />")
    .appendTo("#main_section")
    .dialog({
        "title" : "ABC"
        "width" : 400,
        "height" : 300,
        "modal" : false,
        "resizable" : true,
        "close" : function(){ $(this).remove(); },
        "Cancel" : function(){ $(this).dialog("close"); },
    })
     .draggable({ containment: "parent" });
});
```

The resulting dialog ends up being a direct child of `body`.

I've tried with and without the:

```
appendTo : "#main_section"
```

dialog option.

Here is my updated code:

```
$("#my_button").click(function(){
    $("<div />")
        .dialog()
        .draggable({ containment: "#main_section" });
});
```

My dialog is still not contained to `#main_section` (nor is it a child of it)

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery UI Draggable Containment**

`.draggable({ containment: "#main_section" });`

You need to set boundaries to an element not to the parent...

- Now you can also remove the `appendTo()` after properly containing your dialog

---

Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region.

Multiple types supported:

> **Selector**: The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of the first element found by the selector. If no element is
>    found, no containment will be set.
>
> **Element**: The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of this element.
>
> **String**: Possible values: "parent", "document", "window".
>
> **Array**: An array defining a bounding box in the form [ x1, y1, x2, y2 ].

Comment: I've added an update of my code, it's still not contained withing `#main_section` (also not a child of it either but that is secondary)

Comment: I've updated it again with the simplest stripped down version of what you are proposing. I just can't get it to work.

Comment: `$("<div />")` what is this selecting?

Comment: It's not selecting anything, it's creating a new empty div (and then set's it as a dialog).